# Redirection not working in IE sometimes

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, ajax, survey

I need to override the redirection functionality of "Finish" button in Survey. I have included Survey.js into my site. The code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


 var publishButton = $("input[id$=onetidSaveItem]");
    // change redirection behavior
   publishButton.removeAttr("onclick");
publishButton.click(function SubmitPage(fAddMore, btn) {
    var surveyListName; 
$.ajax({
    url:_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists(guid'"+ _spPageContextInfo.pageListId.replace("{","").replace("}","") +"')",

    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
    success: function (data) {
       // console.log("List Title :" + data.d.Title);
         surveyListName=data.d.Title;
          btn=publishButton;
fAddMore=false;
        var currentUrl = window.location.href;
        currentUrl = currentUrl.substring(0, currentUrl.lastIndexOf('/')-11);
    var formSubmit  = document.forms.frmSubmit;
    var pageCommand = "Cmd=NewField";

    var formAction  =currentUrl+"_layouts/15/mngfield.aspx?i=1" +
                                "&" + pageCommand + "&" +
                                "List="+_spPageContextInfo.pageListId.replace("{","%7B").replace("}","%7D").split('-').join('%2D');
    if (fAddMore)                      
    {
       // var surveyUrl = currentUrl+"_layouts/15/qstNew.aspx/List/"+_spPageContextInfo.pageListId.replace("{","%7B").replace("}","%7D").split('-').join('%2D');
        formSubmit.action = formAction + "&NextUsing=" +  currentUrl.split(':').join('%3A').split('/').join('%2F')+"%5Flayouts%2F15%2FqstNew%2Easpx%2FList%3D"+_spPageContextInfo.pageListId.replace("{","%7B").replace("}","%7D").split('-').join('%2D');

    }
    else
    {
        //setTimeout(function(){ formSubmit.action = formAction + "&NextUsing=" + currentUrl+"Lists/"+surveyListName+"/preview.aspx"; }, 10000);
        formSubmit.action = formAction + "&NextUsing=" + (currentUrl+"Lists/"+surveyListName+"/preview%2Easpx").split(':').join('%3A').split('/').join('%2F');


    }
```

Here the redirection works fine in chrome.It should actually redirect to preview page.But  in IE , it is navigated to mngfield.aspx.

Also, this redirection works fine in IE sometimes.I am not able to guess this issue.

Anyone please help.

Comment: If it work sometimes, then the Server is redirecting. Check the F12 Network tab and see where IE wants to go, and where it is redirect to.

Comment: The url formed on clicking the button is: "http://domain/sites/sitename/_layouts/15/mngfield.aspx?i=1&Cmd=NewField&List=%7B6bb7fc2d%2D450e%2D4ffe%2D990c%2De7919fec1181%7D&NextUsing=http%3A%2F%2Fdomain%3A7566%2Fsites%2FSitename%2FLists%2Flistname%2Fpreview%2Easpx" but i need to redirect to "http://domain/sites/Sitename/Lists/listname/Preview.aspx"

Comment: I do not understand. You set  formAction yourself to ``_layouts/15``

Comment: Try setting the action using document.getElementById("frmSubmit").action

Comment: That is the code from sharepoint for onclick on "Finish" button - @Danny

Comment: Still do not understand, the code you post is not standard SharePoint code.  Someone added this.

Comment: The function SubmitPage(fAddmore,this) is from sharepoint. You can find this onclick of finish button in Survey list.Can you check to clarify it.@Danny